# Проверка принадлежности группе безопасности Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, azure

Имеется Локальная Active Directory и её реплика в Azure Active Directory. Пишу Asp.net приложение с аутентификацией через рабочие аккаунты в облаке, аутентификация работает нормально. Хочу проверить, принадлежит ли пользователь определенной группе с помощью такого кода:

```
User.Identity.IsInRole("имя_группы");
```

или

```
[Authorize(Role = "имя_группы")]
```

Проблема в том, что если в приложении windows-аутентификация, то в локальной AD группы указываются как ДОМЕН\имя_группы (например Contoso\administrators), но в Azure AD же нет доменов? Как правильно указать группу в условии?

Авторизация проходит через ADFS, который в том же Azure.

Comment: Скорее всего там надо будет с айдишкой группы работать, а не с названием.

Comment: @WalterNuss, так айдишка-то не строковая, а метод требует строку :( Пишу айди в кавычках - не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте метод ToString, чтобы привести число к строке, возможно в этом и есть проблема.

Comment: @And а результат разве не один и тот же?)

Answer (score 1):

Так сделайте тестовую страничку, на которой без авторизации выведите список ролей пользователя.

Например, так:

```
public ActionResult Roles()
  => Content(string.Join(",", 
       from claim in ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role)
       select claim.Value));
```

Сразу станет видно в каком формате там роли передаются.

Comment: Может я что-то не так делаю, но у меня функция memberOf для любого пользователя null возвращает.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев что такое "функция memberOf"?

Comment: Ну что-то типа этого https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев я просил не memberof использовать, а посмотреть список ролей пользователя. Вы это сделали?

Comment: Действие вернуло пустую страницу

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев значит, неправильные настройки ADFS

Comment: В сторону каких настроек нужно смотреть?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев в сторону настроек формирования пересылаемых утверждений (claims). Задаются они индивидуально для каждой Relying Party. Под рукой ADFS нет, тем более облачного, так что скриншот не покажу. Может быть, их можно как-нибудь через метаданные федерации настроить.

Comment: Окей, поищем! Спасибо)